# Excel: Summarize rows if two columns have the same string values

Tags: excel, macros, rows

first of all, I don't know much about macros in Excel. I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me out here.
I have a 7000 row table with 3 columns. The first two columns contain string-values, the third integer. I need a function that summarizes my rows, if the same constellation of strings occurs. Example (each character stands for one column):

AB1
JK2
BA1
AB4
FH2
JK1

After running the script, the result should be:

AB5
JK3
BA1
FH2

How would that be possible? Thank you SO much! I need this for a university project in which we visualize weapon trades within military alliances.

Comment: Add a column to concatenate columns 1 and 2.  Then use a Pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Your data is in Sheet1, in columns A, B and C
- The data starts in Row 2
- Your output data is in Sheet2

Without using VBA, you can do:

1. Create a helper column (e.g. column D), which combines Columns A and B. The formula (in D2) would be simply `=$A2 & $B2`
2. To create your output table, you copy the column D in Sheet1 and paste it into eg. column A of Sheet2.
3. Then you select the whole column A (Sheet2) and go to: `Data > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates`
4. In B2 then goes this formula: `=Countif(Sheet1!D:D, $A2)`

You can of course put the helper column somewhere else and hide it. Also, change Sheet1 etc to your actual names.